# Cordova cannot be upgraded to 3.5.1

Tags: cordova

When I try to upgrade my android phonegap app to 3.5.1 due to the warining from Google. The log shows,

```
D:\...\cordova platform update android
Running: android update project --subprojects --path "D:\...e\platforms\android" --target androi
Resolved location of library project to: D:\...\CordovaLib
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
....
Android project is now at version 3.5.0
If you updated from a pre-3.2.0 version and use an IDE, we now require that you import the "CordovaLib" library project.
```

It seems the latest I can get from this command is 3.5.0. Any idea ?

Regards
hammer

Comment: What is returned when you run `cordova --version`?

Answer (score 0):

How about try

```
$ sudo npm update -g cordova
$ cordova update platform android
```